What word embedding model (no contex) to choose in 2024?
I need word embeddings to build a latent space of words (English). I have about 2500 words to embed and then about 9000 to infer basing on some model I'll build. I used word2vec so far, but its coverage isn't great and I'd like something that is used in 2024. I looked into bert, but it's contextualized, while I only have words. I looked into openai's embeddings, but am still not sure as I'd like to run the code as many times as I'd like. I saw the leaderboard, but it's not clear as there are many prompt-based techniques, and I want embeddings. What would you recommend to me?

If you're looking to choose an embedding model, check out the MTEB leaderboard. You can choose a model that performs well on the specific task you have in mind. Of course, any leaderboard is only as good as its metrics and eval suite, but this is a good start. These embedding models don't require prompts.

I checked and they do require prompts! Also I can filtre out some things like prompting, no instructions, but it still seems these embeddings are used for document-sentence-level texts....not words without contexts like in my case!

You can simply embed a single word. Of course, the problem is that the meaning of a word changes with context. But that you can still do. The embedding models do not require prompts.

What would you suggest then?

For this purpose, try something small and proven to start, like https://huggingface.co/BAAI/bge-small-en-v1.5
